# Hard time understanding gridfs and connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

So I watched this video: https://youtu.be/EVIGIcm7o2w

And it explained a lot of stuff. But the problem is I already have a project created with `Express` so my connection is done in app.js like this:

```
// mongodb connection
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./globals/config');
mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected to mongodb. Go to http://localhost:3000 to open app');
});
```

Now I want to use gridFS, ***in a different file*** to upload files to my db, and I tried this:

```
var grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
uploadFile(file) {
    var config = require('./config');
    mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    const gfs = grid(conn.db);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: file.filename,
    });
    fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('close', function (file) {
        console.log(`${file.filename} written to the db`);
    });
}
```

But this makes no sense, since I'm reopening 2 connections. I looked at mongoose-gridfs, but it also showed using it in sort of "app.js" no cross-file way of doing things. How do I use gridfs without opening 2 connections and using 2 different js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate module, let's say `mygridfs.js` and place your function in `module.exports`. Make `mongoose` a parameter to this function:

```
var grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var fs = require('fs');
exports.uploadFile = function(file, mongoose) {
    grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    const gfs = grid(mongoose.connection.db);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: file.filename,
    });
    fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('close', function (file) {
        console.log(`${file.filename} written to the db`);
    });
}
```

In your main `app.js` file, just require the module:

```
var mygridfs= require("mygridfs");
mygridfs.uploadFile(file, mongoose);
```

Comment: But I'm requiring the module not from my app.js file. It's from a different module

Comment: all you need to do is pass the mongoose object to all modules that need it

Comment: Won't passing it like this cause the function to be called?

Comment: which function? once the connection is established the object will encapsulate the connection state...not sure what you mean

Comment: uploadFunction is a function. How can I send something to a module then?

Comment: as I illustrated...your model exports a function F, which received the mongoose parameter. In F you would call uploadFile(file, mongoose). F gets called in app.js where the execution takes place